# jQuery: isotope sorting by date

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, jquery-isotope

I'm sorting a grid of divs by date, but I've encountered a problem. The divs are being sorted by date, but when you introduce another month, it doesn't take that into account and just sorts by the day value.
HTML:

```
<div class="grid-filter">
    <a href="#">
    <div class="grid-block" style="background-color: #46747c" data-category="1952013">
        <div class="block-text date-title">19/05</div>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="grid-filter">
    <a href="#">
    <div class="grid-block" style="background-color: #ebd133" data-category="2552013">
        <div class="block-text date-title">25/05</div>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="grid-filter">
    <a href="#">
    <div class="grid-block" style="background-color: #cc7788" data-category="3052013">
        <div class="block-text date-title">30/05</div>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="grid-filter">
    <a href="#">
    <div class="grid-block" style="background-color: #46747c" data-category="0562013">
        <div class="block-text date-title">05/06</div>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var jQuerycontainer = jQuery('#main-grid');

if(location.hash!=""){
    var hashfilter = "." + location.hash.substr(1);
    }
    else{
    var hashfilter = "*";
    }

jQuerycontainer.imagesLoaded( function(){
jQuerycontainer.isotope({
    filter: hashfilter,
    itemSelector: '.grid-block',
    getSortData : {
    date : function( jQueryelem ) {
    return jQueryelem.attr('data-category');
    }
    },
    sortBy : 'date',
    animationEngine: 'css',
    masonry: {
    columnWidth: 4
    }

});
});

jQuery('.filter-menu a').click(function(){
    var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
    var prettyselector = selector.substr(1);
    location.hash = prettyselector;
    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
    return false;
    });

jQuery('.grid-filter a').click(function(){
    var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
    var prettyselector = selector.substr(1);
    location.hash = prettyselector;
    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
    return false;
    }); 

jQuery(window).hashchange(function(){

                if(location.hash!=""){
                    var hashfilter = "." + location.hash.substr(1);
                }
                else{
                    var hashfilter = "*";
                }


jQuerycontainer.imagesLoaded( function(){
jQuerycontainer.isotope({
    filter: hashfilter,
    itemSelector: '.grid-block',
    getSortData : {
    date : function( jQueryelem ) {
    return jQueryelem.attr('data-category');
    }
    },
    sortBy : 'date',
    animationEngine: 'css',
    masonry: {
    columnWidth: 4
    }
});
});
});
});
```

So the blocks are being sorted, BUT the final one with the date `0562013` is appearing first as 05 is the smallest number I assume, is there anyway to take the month into account also so it will successfully sort the divs by date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuerycontainer.imagesLoaded( function(){
jQuerycontainer.isotope({
    filter: hashfilter,
    itemSelector: '.grid-block',
    getSortData : {
    date : function( jQueryelem ) {
    return date.substring(4,8)+date.substring(2,4)+date.substring(0,2);
    }
    },
    sortBy : 'date',
    animationEngine: 'css',
    masonry: {
    columnWidth: 4
    }

});
});
```

Comment: this didn't seem to work, doesn't seem to sort the divs by date?

Comment: I tried the edited one too, seemed to sort the divs in a random order. I've seen you've changed it back to the one above, I've tried working about with it but I still can't get it to work?

Comment: Can you change the way to generate the date by adding the 0 to the month?

Comment: I can on this page, yes. I've changed the php, the dates now generated have the leading zero, is there now a way to successfully sort by date?

Comment: I edited the answer to achieve you goal. By the way if you can generate the date as you want, it is more easy to return the value in this format (yyyymmdd) directly from you php page. (an you don't need this javascript adaptation)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your date format. The way it is now, you cant distinguish between days and month: `2122013` could be `2.12.2013` as well as `21.2.2013`.

I would suggest the common `Y-M-D` (year-month-day, e.g. `2013-03-07`) format.
**It's sortable by default.** You don't need to change anything else.